# How would i use ->findTaggedServiceIds in a controller?

Tags: symfony

the docs do it like this:

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds(
        'acme_mailer.transport'
    );
}
```

But if i attempt to do this in a controller, i get method not found.

```
public function handlersAction() {
    $handlers = $this->container->findTaggedServiceIds(
        'quickship.handler'
    );
    return View::create($handlers);
}
```

How do i access the ContainerBuilder in a controller?

Comment: Tagged services are only accessed when compiling the container. What is it you are trying to do with the tagged services?

Comment: I am attempting to get an array of services that share a common interface and the same tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findTaggedServiceIds` is a method of [ContainerBuilder](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.html) not of [Container](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.html)

Here is a solution (not the only one) to achieve what you want.

Register your controller as a service, let's say with the id **constroller.service** and add a method

`public function setQuickshipHandlers($handlers){
    //Do something with the services IDs
}`

Next, you write a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to get the tagged services and feed your controller/service with them

Should be something like **YourBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/HandlersPass.php**

```
<?php

namespace YourBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class HandlersPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $controllerServiceDefinition = $container->findDefinition('controller.service');

        $handlers = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('quickship.handler');

        $controllerServiceDefinition->addMethodCall('setQuickshipHandlers',array_keys($handlers);            
    }
}
```

Finally, you add this compiler to your bundle build method.
Should be something like **YourBundle/YourBundle.php**

```
<?php

namespace YourBundle;

use YourBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\HandlersPass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class YourBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new HandlersPass());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to do that after container is compiled.

The way to do that is gather all tagged services in your custom compilerpass and register them in some kind of service.

Then in your controller you will do something like:

```
$services = $this->get('my_service')->getServices();
```